# regex and finite depth non escaped parenthesis matching

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match various cominations of nested matched parentheses that do not exceed a given depth.

If the depth is two, the following should match

```
H<>
H<a>
H<<a><b>>
H<a<b>c<d>>
```

These shoud not:

```
H<<<>>>
H<<<>><<><>><>>
```

I thought I would make a function that generates the regex

```
INNER = r"[^<>]"
OPEN  = r"<"
CLOSE = r">"

def parenthesis(depth=2):
    if depth == 0:
        return INNER
    inner = "("
    for i in range(depth):
        inner += parenthesis(i) + "|"
    inner = inner[:-1]+")*?"
    return "("+OPEN + inner + CLOSE+")"
```

this seems to work (though I'm not completely confident) if I do, for example:

```
re.match("H"+parentthesis(2), "H<<>>")
```

But really I want to match curley brackets that are not escaped. So:

```
OPEN = r"(?<!\\)[\{]"
CLOSE = r"(?<!\\)[\}]"
```

and, something I am unsure of:

```
INNER = r"[^(?<!\\)[\}\{]]"
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas. This is giving me a headache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INNER = r"(?:\\{|\\}|[^{}])"
```

It means an escaped brace, or a character that isn't a brace.